# Easy way to fix Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12:?

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

I got an Easy way to fix  Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12:

Go to app.gradle -> remove the line junit: junit 4.12 and go to tools - > sync gradle once again.

Or watch the 1 minut video.

https://youtu.be/Wf0OavyvYcQ

Answer (score 0):

just add `allprojects` script to project gradle.
just like this:

```
buildscript {
   [...]
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
   [...]
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
}
```

good luck to you!